# How to convert nested array of object into arraylist in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

i have a nested array of object and i want to convert in arraylist like this :
this is my data array of object :

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "",
    "data": [{
            "pasien_docs": [{
                    "ecg": null,
                    "date": "2020-01-21T05:22:01.901Z"
                }, {
                    "ecg": 1.03,
                    "date": "2020-01-21T05:22:02.979Z"
                }, {
                    "ecg": 1.04,
                    "date": "2020-01-21T05:22:04.053Z"
                }, {
                    "ecg": 1.04,
                    "date": "2020-01-21T05:22:05.126Z"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and i want change convert to array like this :

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "",
    "data": [
        [
            "2020-01-21T05:22:01.901Z",
            null
        ],
        [
            "2020-01-21T05:22:01.901Z",
            1, 03
        ]
        [
            "2020-01-21T05:22:01.901Z",
            1.04
        ]
        [
            "2020-01-21T05:22:01.901Z",
            1.04
        ]
    ]
 }
```

i try using map to convert on result like this :

```
result = result.map((u, i) => [
            u.pasien_docs[i].date,
            u.pasien_docs[i].ecg,
        ]);
```

but why i only get result data of one array not four data ? help me please, thankyou..

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "",
    "data": [
        [
            "2020-01-21T05:22:01.901Z",
            null
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: `u` only has a single element, and `i` is the index of `result`, not `u`

Comment: Is it always only one item in `data` array?

Comment: There is no arraylist in Javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```js
const src = {"status":true,"message":"","data":[{"pasien_docs":[{"ecg":null,"date":"2020-01-21T05:22:01.901Z"},{"ecg":1.03,"date":"2020-01-21T05:22:02.979Z"},{"ecg":1.04,"date":"2020-01-21T05:22:04.053Z"},{"ecg":1.04,"date":"2020-01-21T05:22:05.126Z"},]}]},

result = {
  ...src, 
  data: src.data[0].pasien_docs.map(Object.values)
}

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Personal opinion, but i think it looks nicer with `.map(el => Object.values(el))`

Comment: It may be even nicer as `.map(Object.values)`, but I believe it may be somewhat [slower](https://jsbench.me/urkas6q4hj/1)

Comment: is src the same as result?

Comment: @lfaruki : maybe you're right, besides, destructuring syntax may appear more confusing than `Object.values()`, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2):

If you dont wanna use spread operator, this can also do the trick for you

```
const source = {"status":true,"message":"","data":[{"pasien_docs":[{"ecg":null,"date":"2020-01-21T05:22:01.901Z"},{"ecg":1.03,"date":"2020-01-21T05:22:02.979Z"},{"ecg":1.04,"date":"2020-01-21T05:22:04.053Z"},{"ecg":1.04,"date":"2020-01-21T05:22:05.126Z"},]}]}

const result = Object.assign({}, source, {
  data: source.data[0].pasien_docs.map(Object.values)
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I am curious to learn the diffrence between your solution `src.data[0].pasien_docs.map(Object.values)`  and `source.data.map(v => v.pasien_docs.map(Object.values))[0]`, pls point out my mistake where I am going wrong in my case w.r.t mutating?

Comment: You're welcome. Another hint for you to make your code immutable (and yet not identical to mine ;), you may do `Object.assign({}, source, {..`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {
  status: true,
  message: "",
  data: [
    {
      pasien_docs: [
        {
          ecg: null,
          date: "2020-01-21T05:22:01.901Z",
        },
        {
          ecg: 1.03,
          date: "2020-01-21T05:22:02.979Z",
        },
        {
          ecg: 1.04,
          date: "2020-01-21T05:22:04.053Z",
        },
        {
          ecg: 1.04,
          date: "2020-01-21T05:22:05.126Z",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

var finalobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
var innerobj = obj.data;
var intermd = innerobj.map((data) => {
  return data.pasien_docs;
});
finalarray = intermd[0].map((val) => {
  return [val.ecg, val.date];
});
console.log(obj);
finalobj.data[0].pasien_docs=finalarray;
console.log(finalobj);
```